# Facebook Instant Games: Rewarded video failed to preload: Client does not support the message: getrewardedvideoasync

Tags: facebook, instant

When running http-server with SSL I get no errors with instant games SDK.

However the reward video fails to preload.

ERROR

```
Rewarded video failed to preload: Client does not support the message: getrewardedvideoasync
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior, as ads are not supported in the embedded player. This is a known issue. It is is not expected to be addressed in the near term.

Comment: There is an instant games ad SDK, it contains interstitial and reward ads.  This is the SDK I am referring to.  Can you explain more.

Comment: Ads are only supported on Facebook Messenger and Facebook for Android at this time.

Comment: Oh that is to bad :(  But in app purchases work on iOS?

Comment: In App Purchases are only supported for Android and web at this time.